# How can we apply pre position for draggable element in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have so many images on droppable div, i am storing its position top and left in the database, now when i go for the edit, I want to apply its pre position to that draggable element, can anyone please help how can i apply that in this function ?  Draggable is working for me, but i want to preload its position, so user can know what was its last draggable position, thanks 
 I tried this draggable function but it is not working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".draggable_image").draggable({

    }).each(function(ui) {           
        ui.helper.css('position', 'fixed');
        ui.helper.css('top', "<?php echo $drag_string[0]; ?>px");
        ui.helper.css('left', "<?php echo $drag_string[1]; ?>px");
    });
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean from _I want to apply its pre position to that draggable element_?